# Fix "transfromation" typo in tag synonym

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

The "transfromation" synonym should be "transformation". That's just a typo, although it may have been lurking for a while. (I can't see a way to suggest an edit, except this one.)

Comment: We cannot actually change tags, nor can we delete them altogether.  However, because `transfromation` is not associated with any threads, it should automatically disappear within six months.

Comment: Thanks for that crucial information. It comes as a surprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this won't matter since [transfromation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfromation) is already a synonym of [data-transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transformation).  It might be that we need to create a new tag `[transformation]` to *also* be a synonym of [data-transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transformation), but only to preempt the possibility that someone will create that tag without people noticing it.  However, that doesn't seem to have been an issue thus far; we can probably put that off until it actually occurs.

Comment: I don't think you have grasped my point. "transfromation" is a typo (and not even a common one in English). I can't believe it was intended as a tag. Do we maintain misspellings of any other words as tags? Meanwhile the lack of "transformation" is an obvious gap.

Comment: I've missed points before, but I think there is no gap. There isn't supposed to be a `[transformation]` tag. If there were one, it would be a synonym of `[data-transformation]`. The fact that there was a typo in `[transformation]` before it was made into a synonym doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand at all. We fix typos in posts, especially in their titles; aren't typos in tags even more fundamental? What's the objection to deleting it and substituting the correct spelling?

Comment: It's not a typo in a *tag* it's a typo in a *tag synonym*. It can't be "fixed" except by a moderator. I don't object to that if the mods feel like doing it, but note that [typos are part of the point of tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.