# Fix a typo in [restricted-boltzman-machine] (RBM) tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a typo in the [restricted-boltzman-machine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-boltzman-machine) tag. Boltzma**nn** is spelled with a double *n* but the tag currently has a single *n*. From [this Meta post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/fix-transfromation-typo-in-tag-synonym) I got the impression the moderators can fix typos like this. Would any of the moderators kindly do it?

Answer (score 17):

Done.

There's supposed to be a mechanism for users to propose tag synonyms, but it is rarely invoked and never works because it requires (as I recall) five votes for approval and there's no queue to alert people a synonym is pending.

For the record, this change is effected by creating the new tag and merging the old tag with the new as a "synonym."  This process "orphans" the tag wiki (if it exists).  Mods can find orphan wikis in order to recover their text, which I have done.  There's probably a better way to do all this, but what I have described is how it most naturally happens.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was fast and efficient.

Comment: ... for appropriate values of "naturally".